# Mac Books blocking one another from Internet

Tags: wifi

A couple of months ago, I migrated the data from my Air to a new MacBook Pro with migration assistant and shelved the Air.

Recently, we recomishioned the Air for family surfing but noticed that when the Air connected to the Internet through Wi-Fi, the Pro wouldn't connect and vice versa.

In both cases the machine that won't connect says that the Wi-Fi connection is functioning properly. Ive followed all of the standard wi-Fi troubleshooting tips on both machines to no avail.

Both machines have current updates. We also have 4 iPads and 2 phones that can connect with out issue.

Any ideas on how to get both machines connected simultaneously?

Thanks!

Comment: Does either of your Mac's have a static IP?  Go to System Preferences --> Network --> Wifi -> Advanced --> TCP/IP.  Look to see if they are set to Manual and the IP addresses are the same.  If they are on DHCP, again check if they are the same.

Comment: No, neither are static.

Comment: Check for the same IP even if its on DHCP. Also check if the hostnames are the same.